# Object Building across Micro services

Tags: java, oop, domain-driven-design, microservices, soa

We have three micro services MSA, MSB and MSC. The micro service MSA creates a partial object O1 and sends to MSB only through a dedicated message topic. After receiving the partial object O1 from MSA, MSB populates few more attributes in O1 and shares in the common message bus from which MSC consumes the object O1.

Question is that, is this a good approach where the object building is shared across multiple micro services?

Comment: No it is not, why is the objects state to be played with in parts parts? But if you still want to do it you can instead of sharing it like this you can make an inheritance hierarchy & avoid making the object's state partial. Sort of an dependency restriction thing.

Answer (score 2):

Here it's your response:

In object-oriented programming, a God object is an object that knows too much or does too much. The God object is an example of an anti-pattern.

A common programming technique is to separate a large problem into several smaller problems (a divide and conquer strategy) and create solutions for each of them. Once the smaller problems are solved, the big problem as a whole has been solved. Therefore a given object for a small problem need only know about itself. Likewise, there is only one set of problems an object needs to solve: its own problems.

Answer (score 1):

So you have a microservice **Ordering** and a microservice **Pricing**. Both of the microservices need information about the **Product** entity.

You should ask yourself:

- Do those two different worlds realize the Product entity in the same way? Both of them need the same information?
- Will the product information change for the same reasons for both of the microservices?

If no (which is likely the case), you have to add an abstract layer between them, so that you are sure that they use the same language.
If yes, you can keep on sharing the same object.

By the way, these concerns that you have is not a new thing.
Here is Martin Fowler's article about [bounded contexts](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html)

> So instead DDD divides up a large system into Bounded Contexts, each
>   of which can have a unified model - essentially a way of structuring
>   MultipleCanonicalModels.

keywords for further research: *DDD, context map, bounded context, anticorruption layer.*